# Confirming Deliveries with Spring AMQP

Tags: spring-amqp

We're using Spring AMQP in the style of [Spring Remoting with AMQP](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#remoting). I'm setting `x-message-ttl` on every message so that it expires immediately if it cannot be delivered immediately to a consumer. This works great, however, it leaves the producer waiting for the specified value of `replyTimeout` before failing with `RemoteProxyFailureException` (if I recall correctly). Is there any way I can make the producer fail immeditely if the message cannot be delivered (only waiting for the timeout if the message is actually received)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loose coupling of the architecture means there's no indication to the producer of the expiry.

There used to be an `immediate` flag but it was [removed in rabbitmq 3.0](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/11/19/breaking-things-with-rabbitmq-3-0/).

On possible solution would be to configure a DLX/DLQ so the expired message can be consumed by another consumer, which can return an exception to the client.

**EDIT**:

Simply have the fallback consumer implement the same interface and have it throw an exception.

See [this updated test case](https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-amqp/commit/36eb0742ed65b62a750bde0fdc0f448b4f99db2b).

Comment: But then the whole process is encapsulated in methods calls (e.g., `usersService.createUser(user)`. If another consumer is reading from the DLE, how can that be used to generate an exception from inside this method call?

Comment: You simply need the fallback consumer (listening on the DLQ) to implement the same interface as the main service. I updated [one of the test cases](https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-amqp/commit/36eb0742ed65b62a750bde0fdc0f448b4f99db2b) to verify it works as I expected.

Comment: Is there anyway to achieve this without a consumer? I've had moderate success with setting the `mandatory` flag and a publisher return. The publisher return is effectivelly called when a message can't be delivered to a queue, but if I, for instance, throw an exception, the original caller still waits for the timeout (though the exception is thrown, it seems to be done so from another thread). Is there any way to make it throw from the original thread, effectively aborting the timeout?

Comment: ? ... Mandatory is quite different; your original question was about a message being delivered but not consumed. Mandatory is for when the message can't be delivered at all. Yes, the return comes back on a different thread; no, the framework does not currently have a mechanism to wake up the waiting thread when a return is received. It probably wouldn't be too hard for us to do that; feel free to open an ['Improvement' JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP).